# Python - CSV to Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, csv

I need to import a CSV file that has this kind of data ,

```
                       January February March
              Amy      4     3      4
              Ben      5     2      0 
              Clara    0     3.5    4
```

Top Row having month (names) , first column with names (sales) and monthly booking corresponding to the month.

Looking for a way to get Dictionary output like this one , it needs to drop the months with 0

```
                {"Amy": {"January ": 4, "February": 3, "March": 4},
                  "Ben": {"January": 5, "February": 2},
                  "Clara": {"February": 3.5, "March": 4}}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks ,

Rahul

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: First, [`import csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).

Comment: Also note that that's not a quite "well-formatted" csv. The first column is missing a header. Can you edit the file format? It probably would make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's assume you how to get data from csv to variables, check for unique names, invalid data, ..., and you are struggling with excluding `0` values:

***Update**: reading csv file now included in my code:*

```
# Python 3.2
import csv
delimiter = ','
result = {}
with open("data.csv", 'r') as data_file:
    data = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter=delimiter)
    headers = next(data)[1:] # month names starting from 2nd column in csv
    for row in data:
        temp_dict = {}
        name = row[0]
        values = []
        # converting each value from string to int / float
        # (as suggested by OP's example)
        for x in row[1:]:
            try:
                values.append(int(x))
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    values.append(float(x))
                except ValueError:
                    print("Skipping value '{}' that cannot be converted " +
                          "to a number - see following row: {}"
                          .format(x, delimiter.join(row)))
                    values.append(0)
        for i in range(len(values)):
            if values[i]: # exclude 0 values
                temp_dict[headers[i]] = values[i]
        result[name] = temp_dict    
print(result)
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to get headers and csv_data directly thru a csv read command ? ...Tks...help appreciated

Comment: The csv file looks like this             Name,January,February,March
              Amy,4,3,4
              Ben,5,2,0 
              Clara,0,3.5,4

Answer (score 0):

If you know the delimiter of your CSV, you can do:

```
tokens = line.split(delimiter)
tokens = [token.strip() for token in tokens]
```

...for each line of your CSV.  You would need to extract the appropriate values from the first line you parse to get the keys of the inner dictionaries.  After that, to get the key of the outer-most dictionary, you would use `tokens[0]` and so forth.

Now, having said that, your CSV looks more like a fixed-width file than a CSV to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
ifile = open('test.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
rownum = 0
td = {'j': 0, 'f': 0, 'm': 0}
d = {}
for row in reader:
    # Save header row.
    if rownum == 0:
        header = row
    else:
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            if c != 0:
                td[header] = col
        d[row[0]] = td
```